# Setting Nested Keys to False

Tags: javascript, loops, object

I have an object that looks like this:

```
var access = {
  main: false,
  createCatalog: {
    enterCatalogDetails: false,
    selectProducts: true,
    previewStyles: true,
    previewLayout: false
  },
  createBoard: {
    enterBoardDetails: false,
    selectProducts: false,
    previewLayout: false
  }
}
```

For each key, I want to set the value to false.

I have the following function in which I pass the assets object to:

```
 function setInvalidObject (obj){
      var objCount = 0;
      for(var p in obj){
        if(obj.hasOwnProperty(p)){
          objCount++;
          setInvalidObject(obj[p]);
        }
      }
      if(objCount === 0){
        obj = false;
      }
    }
```

It tries to run through, and calls itself wherever it needs to set a key to false. The problem is, it seems to overwrite itself partway through and I can't figure out why this is happening.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need a check if the property is an object and then iterate the object. Then continue the loop. If not an object, set the value to `false`. You do not need a counter for own properties.

```js
function setInvalidObject(obj) {
    var objCount = 0;
    for(var p in obj){
        if (obj.hasOwnProperty(p)) {
            if (obj[p] && typeof obj[p] === 'object') {
                setInvalidObject(obj[p]);
                continue;
            }
            obj[p] = false;
        }
    }
}

var access = { main: false, createCatalog: { enterCatalogDetails: false, selectProducts: true, previewStyles: true, previewLayout: false }, createBoard: { enterBoardDetails: false, selectProducts: false, previewLayout: false } };

setInvalidObject(access);
console.log(access);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```

Or use [`Object.keys`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/keys) and skip the check `hasOwnProperty`.

```js
function setTo(object, value) {
    Object.keys(object).forEach(function (k) {
        if (object[k] && typeof object[k] === 'object') {
            setTo(object[k], value);
            return;
        }
        object[k] = value;
    });
}

var access = { main: false, createCatalog: { enterCatalogDetails: false, selectProducts: true, previewStyles: true, previewLayout: false }, createBoard: { enterBoardDetails: false, selectProducts: false, previewLayout: false } };

setTo(access, false);
console.log(access);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```

Comment: Fantastic. Thank you!